# -webkit-mask-box-image showing the masking image in sets of 4

Tags: css, safari, webkit

I'm having issues with -webkit-mask-box-image showing the masking image in sets of 4 on [my application](https://app.chorechampion.com). This started recently on Safari and doesn't happen on Chrome. Any help would be appreciated.

```
.fhr {
  --fhr-icon-size: 20px;
  &-shopping-bag {
    -webkit-mask-box-image: url("/icons/shopping-bag.svg");
  }
  background: var(--layout-color);
  height: var(--fhr-icon-size);
  width: var(--fhr-icon-size);
}
```

[image: Screenshot from App]

Comment: Can you share the code please?

Comment: @cts Added, you might get more info from inspect too.

Comment: The link you posted takes me no where and I can't inspect an image.

Comment: don't add your answer inside the question. A question needs to remain a question

Answer (score 2):

Hey I was running into the same issue where it was just repeating like that. I couldn't find anything useful on during my searches and it felt like I was the only one running into the issue.

Here is a link I found https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-mask-box-image it appears that we are trying to do a short hand and safari doesn't like it.

To resolve it on my app I replaced `-webkit-mask-box-image` with `-webkit-mask-box-image-source` and that seemed to fix it for me. I hope that helps you, and good luck coding!